# Can sonar be used to monitor only part of my code?

Tags: sonarqube

Hi I got a request to make sonar monitor code quality only for the non legacy parts of my code.

Is it possible ? I cannot find it in sonar configs or anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Cutoff plugin http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Cutoff+Plugin.
Assuming that the legacy part of your system is not modified you can use this plugin to exclude files from analysis based on a cutoff date threshold. Any source file that was last modified prior to the configured cutoff date is excluded.

Comment: Almost what I need, sometimes people have to mess around that legacy code :(

Answer (score 3):

The Sonar documentation on [advanced parameters](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) lists the following property which could could use to exclude parts of your source tree:

```
sonar.exclusions=com/mycompany/*.java,**/*Dummy.java
```

Also possible to set this parameter from the Settings menu of your project.

Comment: It looks like this is a lot of work but might work ! thanks I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the sonar.inclusions setting (available in Sonar 3.5+).

Per http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Administration:
"Set the files to be analyzed through the 'sonar.inclusions' and 'sonar.test.inclusions' properties. In this case, only these very files will be analyzed."

This is also available in the project configuration -> Settings -> Exclusions under "Source File Inclusions"